# QMainDialog become modal if has modal QDialog as parent on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, qdialog, qmainwindow

I create QMainWindow with parent widget which is modal QDialog. QMainWindow created as modl window ontop of dialog and doesn't has active close, minimize buttons and has grayed(unaccessable) menu.

I suppose access to QMainWindow's menu restricted since there is 
QDialog with modal flag active. But I need to have a non modal QMainWindow with menu which can be accessed.

Is it possible? I use qt 4.5.2 and os x lion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble imagining the context in which one would open a `QMainWindow` parented to a modal `QDialog`.

However, if you want the `QMainWindow` to act as a top-level window, don't set a parent.

Comment: In this case it will be overlapped by `QDialog`(which was parent in previous case).